# Making a Message Appear if the Results of a Query Are Zero

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable called `$uid`, and I would like to print a message if the variable $uid is not contained in the "loginid" field of a MySQL table "tweets" on any row that has another variable, `$submissionid`.  I think my query `$tweetquery` is okay.  Basically, I would like the message to echo if the loginid variables pulled from "tweets" never equal $uid.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$tweetquery = "SELECT loginid
               FROM tweets 
              WHERE submissionid = '$submissionid'";


   $tweetresult = mysql_query($tweetquery);         

   if...

echo '<div>Message</div>';
```

Comment: Obligatory comments regarding use of PDO's and SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`mysql_num_rows($result)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

```
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
{
  // Do something
}
else
{
  echo 'No results';
}
```

Comment: @cwallenpoole makes a good point above. You should rewrite the query as `$tweetquery = "SELECT loginid FROM tweets WHERE submissionid = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($submissionid) . "'";`. See [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Call me crazy, but using `mysql_num_rows` is not the way I'd do this. `mysql_fetch_array` does not do anything destructive if nothing is returned, so call that as normal.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $resource );
if(!$row)
{
    //do what you would do if the query returned nothing
}
else
{
   do
   {
      // do what you would do with the row
   } while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $resource ) );
}
```

The problem with `mysql_num_rows` is that it actually represents a call to the database asking for how many rows exist in the pointer. It is a, frankly, needless back-and-forth which can easily be avoided. So why not avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($tweetresult) > 0)
     // results found
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($tweetresult) == 0) {
    echo 'Message';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_num_rows()` returns the numbers of rows fetched from the database. If rows fetched are zero `echo` a message.

```
$tweetquery = "SELECT loginid
           FROM tweets 
          WHERE submissionid = '$submissionid'";


$tweetresult = mysql_query($tweetquery);         

if(mysql_num_rows($tweetresult) > 0){
    // your results here
} else {

    echo '<div>Message</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($tweetresult) == 0)
    echo "<div>Message</div>";
else {
    //Do something if $uid was found
}
```